# Trying to fill a PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, while-loop

On a previous page, I have gotten the names and the number of playeys values from the user.

I wish to fill them into an array. Here is my code so far:

```
<?php

$numberOfPlayers = $_POST['numberOfPlayers'];
$counter = 1;
$playerName = array();

while($counter<=$numberOfPlayers-1){
$playerName[$counter-1]= $_POST[$counter];
$counter=$counter+1;
}  

print_r($playerName);

?>
```

However it is throwing out an error saying "Undefined offset: 1 in C:\wamp\www\test.php on line 8".

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: `$_POST['1']` does not exist.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `array_push()`. or `[]` array short hand. No need to use a counter.

```
while($numberOfPlayers--){
    if(isset($_POST[$numberOfPlayers]))
        $playerName[]= $_POST[$numberOfPlayers];
}
```

Comment: This isn't exactly what I want. I need to populate the array so I need the counter. There are many player names, but the amount of players vary depending on what the user has chossen on the previous screen.

Comment: Does  `$_POST['numberOfPlayers']` contain the total number of players or total selected number for players?

Comment: It contains the total number of players.

Comment: This also doesnt work. This would only assign the numberofplayer to the playerName array. I want the names stored in the playerName array.

Thanks for the help though man.

Comment: could you show what does `var_dump($_POST)` contain. You must show your data layout. Otherwise I can not code just blindly.